# Javascript frameworks just "markup" for javascript?

Tags: javascript, frameworks

I am a little curious about how javascript frameworks work. Web development isn't really my area of expertise (I'm more of a c/c++ guy), but do javascript frameworks get translated into vanilla javascript?

Upon inspection of website source, it seems like it is mostly just standard javascript. Do these javascript engines just translate code into javascript on the server side?

Comment: Whatever code frameworks use, the eventual code that clients receive is in plain Javascript. It's different in Node, where non-Javascript can be used too. There's also WebAssembly I guess

Comment: Yes, they get translated into vanilla JS, since that's all the browser ultimately understands. But it's all done on the client side.

Comment: @RobinZigmond So web browsers know to translate these frameworks natively?

Comment: The web browser only receives html, css, javascript or WebAssembly. Some frameworks require a build step before generating what gets received by the browser.

Comment: @EliKolb no of course not. There is usually some build step before hand to translate the project into JS which can be understood by the browser. And all these frameworks involve loading external JS library code which is needed for the generated JS code to work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, most of **JavaScript** Frameworks translates the code you write to vanilla **JavaScript**, however, this does not happen on the **Server Side**, that would be really slow (**Server side code** is used to check databases, serve files, authenticate, etc.). This process of translation is done **in compilation time** (Although it is translation). (Just like when you compile c++ code into binary).

When it's source code to source code like *JavaScript and React (JSX)* to *Vanilla JavaScript (JS)*, it's translation. When it's source code to binary like *C++ source code* to *an executable (.exe)* is compilation.

After you're done writting your **JavaScript** code with frameworks, you most translate it to **Vanilla JavaScript** (if you also used other uncommon languages to write styles, you must translate them too, like SASS instead of CSS). It is also common to minify it, so it can load faster.

All this is mainly done by tools like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org).

When your site is up and running, we can say that is **run time**.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the fact that they were written in js they would be resolved to js before running and as Robin said they are executed on client side except Node which is a runtime environment and not a framework